# ¿Como puedo relacionar 2 tablas en una relación de Muchos a Muchos?

Tags: base-de-datos, aplicación-web

Tengo dos tablas: **Usuarios** y **Trabajos**.
La tabla **Usuarios** tiene los campos ***Id***, ***Nombre*** y ***Rol***.
La tabla **Trabajos** tiene los campos ***Id***, ***Area*** y ***Descripción***.

La relación de estas tablas es de **M:N**, por ende se genera una tercera tabla que llamaré **Trabajo_usuarios**.

La tabla **Trabajo_usuario** tiene los campos o llaves foraneas **Id_usuarios**, **Id_trabajos**

Lo que necesito es poder almacenar en **Trabajo_usuarios** quien ha publicado un trabajo y quien lo ha realizado teniendo en cuenta el Rol del usuario.

Los usuarios pueden tener dos roles ***Trabajador*** y ***Empleador***. Teniendo esto en cuenta, eso quiere decir que en la tabla **Trabajo_usuarios** van a ver usuarios que son de rol **Trabajadores** y otros **Empleadores**. Ahora ***¿Como saber quien hace la publicaión del trabajo y quien realiza el trabajo?***

Obviamente si un usuario tiene el rol de ***Empleador*** y publica un trabajo, otro usuario con rol de ***Trabajador*** puede realizar ese trabajo, y eso es lo que quiero poder almacenar para futuras consultas.

Espero haberme podido explicar y puedan ayudarme.

Comment: Como ya te comente en otra oportunidad, esto es un problema de las reglas de tu negocio, y tiene que ver con que aspecto de la BD queres priorizar. Hay muchas formas de hacer esto (agregar un campo mas a esa tabla, agregar un flag que lo especifique).

Comment: Manito estas en lo cierto pero, el problema es el siguiente...no se como hacerlooo, osea, tengo las dos tablas, hice las relaciones de acuerdo a lo que necesito, PERO,puedo guardar el Id del trabajo y el Id del usuario.  Por ejemplo : publico un trabajo con mi Id = 1 y mi Rol = Empleador, ahora, tu lo vas a realizar como un usuario con Rol = Trabajador.  Pregunta tecnica ¿Como puede almacenar el usuario tuyo con rol de trabajador y el usuario mio con rol de empleador, si los dos estamos en la misma tabla de usuarios?

Comment: ya te dije, hay muchas formas para hacerlo, y depende principalmente de las reglas de tu negocio (las cuales no conozco) y de que quieras priorizar a la hora de recuperar los datos. Deberas probar con cualquiera de los metodos que te nombre, y trabajar desde alli lo que convenga a tu negocio. (como ejemplo, y esto no es solucion pero soluciona el problema, agrega dos campos, uno que diga usuario empleado, otro usuario trabajador, y guarda cada id de usuario ahi.. pero que pasa si mañana agregan el rol controlador?)